# Eclipse 4 RCP did not inject object to my class

Tags: java, eclipse, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm trying to inject an object to my own class (`OpenProjectItemHandler`) as below context. But the injected object (`eventBroker`) is null. How can we inject the object?

```
public class ProjectExplorerPart {

    protected TreeViewer viewer;

    //@Inject IEventBroker eventBroker;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createComposite(Composite parent) {
        //...
        viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new OpenProjectItemHandler());

        //...
    }
}


public class OpenProjectItemHandler implements IDoubleClickListener {

    @Inject IEventBroker eventBroker;

    @Override
    public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
            //...
            //IEclipseContext eclipseContext = E4Workbench.getServiceContext();
            //eventBroker = eclipseContext.get(IEventBroker.class);
            eventBroker.send("ta/project_explorer/open_item", Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects created using `new` are not injected. You need to use `ContextInjectionFactory.make` to create the object.

```
public class ProjectExplorerPart {

  protected TreeViewer viewer;

  @PostConstruct
  public void createComposite(Composite parent, IEclipseContext context) {
    //...

    OpenProjectItemHandler handler
        = ContextInjectionFactory.make(OpenProjectItemHandler.class, context);

    viewer.addDoubleClickListener(handler);

    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks greg! I'm just new to RCP and DI. I have read many documents but didn't see this knowledge. Can you share me the document about those knowledge?

Comment: I generally look at Lars Vogel's [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) and his book. But I also just read the source code a lot.

Comment: Maybe this is useful for someone else https://www.eclipsecon.org/2013/sites/eclipsecon.org.2013/files/E4_Injection_OPCoach_talk_0.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to annotate the class you want to inject with the `@Creatable` annotation like this:

```
@Creatable
@Singleton
public class OpenProjectItemHandler implements IDoubleClickListener {
   ...
}
```

And then use standard injection in object managed by the framework to inject your instance

```
public class ProjectExplorerPart {
   @Inject private OpenProjectItemHandler opih;
   @PostConstruct
   public void createComposite(Composite parent) {
    //...
    viewer.addDoubleClickListener(opih);
    //...
   }
```

}